# achartengine - different colors for different points and lines

Tags: android, charts, line, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine to visualize measurement values in a line chart view. The visualization itself works already however one important part is missing and I have no idea how to implement it. Each circle represents a measurement value and the color of each circle depends on the value of the measurement.
Does anybody know how to change the color of a circle as shown in the image?

[image: http://whiterabbitsoftware.com/images/whiterabbit/misc/line_chart.png]

thx and cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to create several series of data. Each series is responsible for rendering the points of a given color.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This approach I've tried already, it resulted in colored circles as desired however there were no connection lines between the circles :/

Comment: http://s14.directupload.net/images/130812/nplg22i8.png that's how it looks like if I use a series for each data point. btw. does anybody know how I can shift the graph so that the most left and right point is fully visible? thx and chreers

Comment: Use renderer.setXAxisMax();

Comment: thx Dan, setXAxisMax was perfekt - for shifting the graph in the right position. yet only the lines between the circles are missing :)

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that every point has a separate color to the others. In this case maybe have a few series and each one would be used to connect points. Keep the existing ones that render the points only and add a yellow series, an orange one, a green one and so on that would only connect points.

Comment: @Dan : Hello here i am not getting your thing,can you elaborate thing.I have to draw line where some X value skip and attach with position from 0 to 4 direct and need  gap also.
ex. if i need skip 26 X value then draw 25 to 27